# Redirect / hijack static framework method (change return value)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to extend a .Net application.

Therefore I’ve loaded the 3rd party assembly into a newly created `AppDomain` and invoked the `EntryPoint`.

My Problem is that the 3rd party application depends on `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly`, but this method returns my assembly witch leads to errors.

My idea was to intercept / hijack or **replace this function** by a custom one which then returns the “correct” assembly.

There fore, I had a look at this Article: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/37549/clr-injection-runtime-method-replacer witch works like expected on custom functions but does **not seem to have any effect** on `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly`.

As I don’t really now much about the underlaying concepts of .Net (IL & JIT): How could this be done?

**At the end, it should look something like this:**
(Sorry for the vb )

[image]

Comment: Have you seen https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/resolve-loads ? you can get an event when the domain tries to resolve a dll and you can change the outcome there.

Comment: Yes, I’m actually already using this event for dependency resolving. But that doesn’t solve my problem cause I only want to change the result of the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` function. I can’t recreate the whole assembly for that, can I?

Comment: Can't you use the resolve event and instead of it resolving to your own assembly you make it resolve to the right assembly? Or does GetExecuting assembly not work that way? anyhow i don't think there is a reasonable way to change the method. Another idea: what if you decompile the assembly, change where GetExecutingAssembly is called and then recompile to get a working assembly?

Comment: No, that’s not how this event works. As far as I know, this event will only be fired if the system can’t find a assembly file and let’s you do the search.

Comment: The `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` function is part of `mscorlib.dll`. This assembly get’s loaded in any `AppDomain` right at the beginning and always get’s loaded from the .Net Assembly directory (although Xamarin & Unity have ways to load a custom `mscorlib`). (Loading a patched file is not really possible)

Answer (score 0):

I know use `AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly`. It seems that the CLR returns the “right” assembly if I start the assembly this way.
Before (Not working as expected):

```vb
Try
    Dim app = Assembly.LoadFrom(path)
    Dim args() As String = {}
    app.EntryPoint.Invoke(Nothing, {args})
Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.Print(ex.Message)
End Try
```

After (Working as expected):

```vb
Dim domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(...)
domain.ExecuteAssembly(vMixApplicationPath)
```

But I’d still be interested in why the replacing of this method did not work…